# Mapping { with Vimscript

Tags: vimscript, vimrc

I have been trying to map `{` in insert mode to the following if the line contains any character other than blank or tabs: **`<CR>{<CR>`** and to **`{<CR>`** if the line is blank (contains at most spaces or tabs), how would you do this? I am assuming vimscript is needed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but you could try this:

```
function! s:InsertBrace() abort
    if getline('.') =~ '\S'
        return "\n{\n"
    else
        return "{\n"
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <expr> { <sid>InsertBrace()
```

**Edit**

If your vim version doesn't support vimscript functions, you could try the following:

```
inoremap <expr> { getline('.') =~ '\S' ? "^M{^M" : "{^M"
```

However, do not type `^M` literally, instead type `<C-v>` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will insert a carriage return character literally which vim displays with its caret notation `^M`.

Comment: ya this is what I wanted! It works in vim but I happen to use an emulation of vim that doesn't support vimscript functions (i just realized this) do happen to know any other way to do this? Thanks in any case.

Comment: @fYre I don't know if it will work with your vim version, but I've edited my answer to propose an alternative. I hope it will work.

Comment: @fYre If it doesn't produce what you want, you should probably update your question, add a little more information (your vim version and which features it was compiled with) and refuse my answer as being a solution to your problem. Someone else will probably have another working solution for your vim version.